# java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null while get json file from server

Tags: android, httpclient

I got following error. java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null while get json file from server.I googled but cant find any solution for this.

**My Code:**

```
try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            Log.i("clock", httpPost.getURI().toString());
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Log.i("Buffer", "1");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            Log.i("Buffer", "2");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Log.i("Buffer", "3");
            String line = null;
            Log.i("Buffer", "4");
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            Log.i("Buffer", "5");
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.i("Buffer", "6->"+json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result-> " + e.toString());
        }
```

**Logcat:**

[image]

Comment: If you logged the whole stacktrace instead of the exception's message only, you would know on what line the problem is.

Comment: please post full logcat post, please make sure that you have added internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always check the `instance/ java object` is `not null` before using it anytime.

eg.

```
if( httpResponse != null){
    //todo your work here with "httpResponse "
}
```

and

```
if(is !=null){
   //todo your work here with "is"
}
```

---

**Here is the code example if I would communicate with server**

```
// this method takes URL as input and returns JSON data 
//parent class name is "NewWebHelper.java"

public String getResult(String url) {

        Log.v(TAG, "Final Requsting URL is : :"+url);

        String line = "";
        String responseJsonData = null;

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String x = "";
            URL httpurl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection  tc= httpurl.openConnection();   

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                              new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

            if(in !=null){
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                x = sb.toString();
            }
            responseJsonData = new String(x);

            }
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException uh){            
            Log.v("NewWebHelper", "Unknown host :");
            uh.printStackTrace();
        }
       catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           Log.v("NewWebHelper", "FileNotFoundException :");
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("NewWebHelper", "IOException :");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      catch (Exception e) {
          Log.v("NewWebHelper", "Exception :");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseJsonData;
    }
```

---

Let me know if you have any trouble regrading this.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
        JSONObject jRoot = new JSONObject(json);
        if (!jRoot.isNull("response")) {

            JSONObject jChat = jRoot.getJSONObject("response");

            if (!jChat.isNull("type")) {
                ch.setType(jChat.getString("type"));
            }
```

Use function `isNull` or use condition `if (is != null)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give permission for Internet access in Manifests.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

worked for me...